# Add Extra Property to Cowboy Request

Tags: erlang, websocket, cowboy

We used Erlang/Cowboy to develop a simple chatting service based on WebSockets. When user connects in, an authentication would be done based on the URL parameter, and it would return user id or none for the connection.

My stupid question is, how to store the user id into the Request data structure and the user id can be get for later-on processes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `cowboy_rest` you can use the `handler_state` to store your user data after authorization. Something like:

```
-record(rs_state{user}).
rest_init(Req, Opts) ->
    {ok, Req, #rs_state{}}.

is_authorized(Req, State) ->
    %% authentication code
    {ok, User} = ...
    {true, Req, State#rs_state{user=User}}}.
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. I thought to store user id to Req, that's wrong, should store to State.